# C# GeoCoordinate not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gps, geolocation

I am currently trying to develop a program that shows the current position on earth for a robot which has an inbuild GPS.
I am using GeoCoordinate but it just doesn't seem to wanna show any data.

**[This is my full code](http://pastie.org/9450130)**

When I use "Step into" to see how it reads the code it just skips everything from line 35 and down.

I'm using my development PC when testing so the first time I tested I had to add a position in  Windows.
My dev PC does not have a GPS.
.NET 4.5.2 is installed.
I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012.

If you need more info, please ask!

Thank you!!

Comment: Well, it would be useful to see actual code instead of line numbers where it doesn't work...

Comment: I added a link to pastie where my full code is.
http://pastie.org/9450130

I thought it was a bit too long and would have filled a lot on the post.

Yes. I'm new here :-D

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your event handler methods?

Comment: Well I did go through the whole code by using breakpoint from start to end by using F11 (Step into) and when it reads my event handlers it just kind of passes over them. I'm not sure if this was the answer you were searching for so please let me know.

Comment: The code at lines 29 and 30 does not actually execute the event handlers, so F11 is not going to show you the execution of those methods. Add a breakpoint in the event handler methods so that when the events are fired the code will debugger kick in.

Comment: Nothing happens. The debugger does not kick in at any point if I add breakpoints in my methods.